# Creating an XML layout from an already existing View

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a `View` that up to now I have been creating programmatically. I wish to instead create a template, and then load that template via a `LayoutInflater` in future. Is it possible to create the template as `XML` from the programmatically created `View`, or must I manually create it through `XML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to automatically generate an XML from code. You'll have to do the conversion manually.

Answer (score 3):

You have to manually create an xml file and use it as template. Programmatically it is not possible.